# How to use different env for different projects?

Tags: python, unix

I have two projects running on a server. I'm storing AWS_SECRET in env.

I set those env in my ~/.bash_profile. How do I make sure that one project gets the correct key? Can I set env only on project scope?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the AWS CLI (`aws`) specifically, you can use "[profiles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-multiple-profiles)", which you can select with the `--profile` argument. For example, in your `~/.aws/credentials`:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY

[user2]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=je7MtGbClwBF/2Zp9Utk/h3yCo8nvbEXAMPLEKEY
```

Then use `aws --profile user2` to select the non-default profile as a one-off, or set the environment variable `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=user2` in your shell to make it permanent. This might be easier than setting `AWS_SECRET` directly, because profile names are actually something you can remember :)

Besides credentials, profiles also let you switch other settings, like `region`.

Comment: This is nice however, I have other secret keys besides AWS ones

Answer (score 0):

On thing you can do is set the environment variables on runtime.

Example:

```
$ AWS_SECRET="Secret1" run_server1 arg1 arg2 arg3
$ AWS_SECRET="Secret2" run_server2 arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Answer (score 0):

[Autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv) is built for this for this exact purpose:

```
pip install autoenv
echo 'AWS_SECRET="Secret1"' > ./project1/.env
echo 'AWS_SECRET="Secret2"' > ./project2/.env
```